# how to run mediation analysis after multiple imputation in R?

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, mediation

I have run a multiple imputation model and after it I used the with() and pool() functions to pool all my results using linear regression to get one estimate.

I want to run mediation analysis on this dataset. I used the complete() function to use one of the imputed datasets, but the problem is that the direct estimate I am getting from this dataset is different (in terms of significance) compared to the results of the linear regression model that came from the pool() function. I believe pool() is more accurate.

How do I run mediation analysis while considering the estimates I am getting from all the imputed datasets?

Here is the code for linear regression after multiple imputation:

`X <- with(imputed_data, lm( I(as.numeric(v1) + as.numeric(v2) + as.numeric(v3) + as.numeric(v4) + as.numeric(v5) + as.numeric(v6) + as.numeric(v7) + as.numeric(v8)) ~ group_post ))`

I am using the mediation package to run the mediation analysis. When I add this model to moderation function, I get an error "Error in model.frame.default(model.m) : object is not a matrix"

Comment: I'm not very familiar with mediation analysis, but wouldn't that also be part of the estimates you're supposed to get from each imputation separately?

Comment: Mediation analysis is different  kind of analysis. It is seperate from the linear model results I get.

Comment: Well yes, you'd run the linear model and then the mediation on each imputation separately, then combine the mediation results. Otherwise your mediation would not include the additional imputation uncertainty, unless that is somehow taken from the combined linear parameter estimates.

Comment: After running mediation multiple times, how do I pool their results?

Comment: The underlying idea would be exactly the same as for your linear regression. A diagonal reading of the `mediator` documentation suggests that it does not return standard errors directly, so you can either use the bootstrap method therein or back-transform from the confidence intervals. I assume you're combining the linear regression estimates through Rubin's rules, so you'd do the same for the mediation parameters and their standard errors.